# display the difference of two values of two columns from two different dataframes without losing the other columns

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter

I've got two dataframes with different values of "d" but have the same values of "a" and "b"

this is df1

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('c', 'd', 8),
    ('e', 'f', 8),
    ('c', 'j', 9),
], ['a', 'b', 'd'])
​
df1.show()
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  d|
+---+---+---+
|  c|  d|  8|
|  e|  f|  8|
|  c|  j|  9|
+---+---+---+
```

and this is df 2

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('c', 'd', 7),
    ('e', 'f', 3),
    ('c', 'j', 8),
], ['a', 'b', 'd'])
df2.show()
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  d|
+---+---+---+
|  c|  d|  7|
|  e|  f|  3|
|  c|  j|  8|
+---+---+---+
```

and i want to obtain the difference between the values of column "d" but also i want to keep the columns "a" and "b"

```
df3 
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  d|
+---+---+---+
|  c|  d|  1|
|  e|  f|  5|
|  c|  j|  1|
+---+---+---+
```

i tried doing a subtract between the two dataframes but it didn't work

```
df1.subtract(df2).show()
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  d|
+---+---+---+
|  c|  d|  8|
|  e|  f|  8|
|  c|  j|  9|
+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, on = ['b', 'a'], how = 'outer').select('a', 'b', (df1.d - df2.d).alias('diff'))

df3.show()
```

Comment: glad! you can upvote the answer so that others also find it useful too.

Comment: i'd love to do that but i still don't have enough reputations to be able to do it 